# Specify the from user when sending email using the mail command

Tags: linux, email, redhat

Does anyone know how to change the from user when sending email using the mail command? I have looked through the man page and can not see how to do this.

We are running Redhat Linux 5.

Comment: removed 'duplicate' tag. I believe the usage of this tag is not encouraged.

Comment: You would probably have got the answer to this question a lot faster by just typing "man mail", which will show you the manual for the command.

Comment: `-r from@address.com` - RHEL7 FYI

Answer (score 30, accepted):

http://www.mindspill.org/962 seems to have a solution.

Essentially:

`echo "This is the main body of the mail" | mail -s "Subject of the Email" recipent_address@example.com -- -f from_user@example.com`

Comment: Doesn't seem to pass the sniff-test. `--` marks end of options to `getopt(3)`, so how would `-f` possibly work as an option after `--`?  Also, reading the man page for (bsd) `mail` on Ubuntu doesn't mention any such `-f` argument support.  Lastly, testing this on Ubuntu 14.04 (with some disbelief and slight hope) shows that indeed it doesn't work.  FWIW (hard to believe again) the original mindspill.org  URL says it works on Red Hat without specifying a version.

Comment: Use the `-v` option for Verbose output `mail -v -s ...`. If the mail fails to deliver due to an improperly configured mail server for example, the smtp command log will show what has gone wrong.

Comment: in debian 9 -f is used to pass a filename

Answer (score 80):

You can specify any extra header you may need with -a

```
$mail -s "Some random subject" -a "From: some@mail.tld" to@mail.tld
```

Comment: @michabbb not working on my Debian Wheezy, result: "From: some@mail.tld: No such file or directory"

Comment: Have you wrapped your param in quotes as in the example above?

Comment: yes with quotes like your example and it displays the error I wrote. But the mail -r option is working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119390/specify-the-from-user-when-sending-email-using-the-mail-command#comment-45619737 (btw don't forget the @username mention if you you want people to get notifications about your replies)

Comment: also working on ubuntu 14.04 (`/etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/bsd-mailx`), but not on 16.04 (`/etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/s-nail`)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu Xenial after `apt-get install mailutils`.

Answer (score 27):

mail -r from@from.from -R from@from.com

-r = from-addr
-R = reply-to addr

The author has indicated his version of mail doesn't support this flag. But if you have a version that does this works fine.

Comment: The -r is not a valid option for the mail command option for the version of mail we have.

Comment: On Debian Wheezy, -r is working on mail command for editing From address but -R is not working for editing ReplyTo address.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else -r DOES affect which address is checked for spf records

Comment: Works fine with Postfix on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: -r worked for me and went to my gmail acct and not delayed spam (after configuring spf/dkim) BUT not the -R flag which wasn't a part of the original question anyway.

Answer (score 21):

When sending over SMTP, the `mail` man page advises to set the `from` variable, in this way (Tested on CentOS 6):

```
mail -s Subject -S from=sender@example.com recipient@example.com
```

You could also attach a file using the `-a` option:

```
mail -s Subject -S from=sender@example.com -a path_to_attachement recipient@example.com
```

Comment: Works for me on CentOS 7.5

Answer (score 7):

None of these worked for me (Ubuntu 12.04) but finally with trial & error I got:

```
echo 'my message blabla\nSecond line (optional of course)' | 
mail -s "Your message title"
-r 'Your full name<yourSenderAdress@yourDomain.abc>'
-Sreplyto="yourReplyAdressIfDifferent@domain.abc"
destinatorEmail@destDomain.abc[,otherDestinator@otherDomain.abc]
```

(all in one line, there is no space in "-Sreplyto")

I got this mail command from:

```
apt-get install mailutils
```

Answer (score 5):

You can append sendmail options to the end of the mail command by first adding --. -f is the command on sendmail to set the from address. So you can do this:

mail recipient@foo.com -- -f sender@bar.com

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me. And it took me long to figure it out, hopefully this helps the next guy.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with mailutils v2.1.

I found this solutions somewhere on the net, don't know where, can't find it again:

```
-aFrom:Servername-Server@mydomain.com
```

Full Command used:

```
cat /root/Reports/ServerName-Report-$DATE.txt | mail -s "Server-Name-Report-$DATE" myemailadress@mydomain.com -aFrom:Servername-Server@mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725/change-the-from-address-in-unix-mail).

The second easiest solution after -r (which is to specify a From: header and separate it from the body by a newline like this

```
 $mail -s "Subject" destination@example.com
 From: Joel <joel@example.com>

 Hi!
 .
```

works in only a few mail versions, don't know what version redhat carries).

PS: Most versions of mail suck!

Answer (score 2):

Most people need to change two values when trying to correctly forge the from address on an email.  First is the from address and the second is the orig-to address.  Many of the solutions offered online only change one of these values.

If as root, I try a simple mail command to send myself an email it might look like this.

`echo "test" | mail -s "a test" me@noone.com`

And the associated logs:

`Feb  6 09:02:51 myserver postfix/qmgr[28875]: B10322269D: from=<root@myserver.com>, size=437, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  6 09:02:52 myserver postfix/smtp[19848]: B10322269D: to=<me@noone.com>, relay=myMTA[x.x.x.x]:25, delay=0.34, delays=0.1/0/0.11/0.13, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 0000014b5f678593-a0e399ef-a801-4655-ad6b-19864a220f38-000000)`

Trying to change the from address with -- 

`echo "test" | mail -s "a test" me@noone.com -- dude@thisguy.com`

This changes the orig-to value but not the from value:

`Feb  6 09:09:09 myserver postfix/qmgr[28875]: 6BD362269D: from=<root@myserver.com>, size=474, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Feb  6 09:09:09 myserver postfix/smtp[20505]: 6BD362269D: to=<me@noone>, orig_to=<dude@thisguy.com>, relay=myMTA[x.x.x.x]:25, delay=0.31, delays=0.06/0/0.09/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 0000014b5f6d48e2-a98b70be-fb02-44e0-8eb3-e4f5b1820265-000000)`

Next trying it with a -r and a -- to adjust the from and orig-to.

`echo "test" | mail -s "a test" -r dude@comeguy.com me@noone.com -- dude@someguy.com`

And the logs:

`Feb  6 09:17:11 myserver postfix/qmgr[28875]: E3B972264C: from=<dude@someguy.com>, size=459, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Feb  6 09:17:11 myserver postfix/smtp[21559]: E3B972264C: to=<me@noone.com>, orig_to=<dude@someguy.com>, relay=myMTA[x.x.x.x]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.56/0.24/0.11/0.17, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 0000014b5f74a2c0-c06709f0-4e8d-4d7e-9abf-dbcea2bee2ea-000000)`

This is how it's working for me.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

on CentOs5: -r from@me.omg

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "This is the main body of the mail" | mail -s "Subject of the Email" recipent_address@example.com -- -f from_user@example.com -F "Elvis Presley"
```

or

```
echo "This is the main body of the mail" | mail -s "Subject of the Email" recipent_address@example.com -aFrom:"Elvis Presley<from_user@example.com>"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on Centos7

`echo "This is the main body of the mail" | mail -s "Subject of the Email" -r seneder_address@whatever.com recipent_address@example.com`

Comment: -r displayname<seneder_address@whatever.com>

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from 2018, on Debian 9 stretch.

Note the `-e` for echo to allow newline characters, and `-r` for mailx to show a name along with an outgoing email address:

```
$ echo -e "testing email via yourisp.com from command line\n\nsent on: $(date)" | mailx -r "Foghorn Leghorn <sender@yourisp.com>" -s "test cli email $(date)" -- recipient@somedomain.com
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS here is the working command :

```
mail -s Subject -S from=sender@example.com recipient@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all example providers, some worked for some not.
Below is another simple example format that worked for me.

```
echo "Sample body" | mail -s "Test email" from=sender-addrs@example.com recepient-addres@example.com
```