# linux mail using wrong domain to send an email

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am using linux "mail" client. When I try to send an email **echo "test" | mail -s "testing" myemail@personal.com** I receive a 550 error bounce back because the domain is invalid.

On the server there are 2 domains. One is public the other is strictly internal. How do I force only the mail client to use the public domain?

Here is the failure message.

```
Final-Recipient: RFC822; myemail@personal.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.8
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.1.8 Invalid domain: server_hostname.internal.domainname
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 12:22:06 -0500
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119390/specify-the-from-user-when-sending-email-using-the-mail-command ?

Comment: Is there any way to specify this in a configuration rather than command line? We have multiple scripts utilizing the command.

Comment: Seems like for plain `sendmail` the configuration line is `define('confDOMAIN_NAME', 'example.com')dnl`, but I never worked with it and thus did not test that.

Answer (score 1):

The fix ended up by modifying the submit.cf and sendmail.cf in /etc/mail/

```
# my official domain name
# ... define this only if sendmail cannot automatically determine your domain
Djdomain_name
```

You need to include the Dj which will be followed by the hostname.

Thank you for everyones help.

Comment: Did not helped for me :(